# Usercontrol Datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, user-controls, datasource

In my current windows application I am looking on how to give a datasource to my usercontrol.
On my page I add my own usercontrol in a flowlayoutpanel, the usercontrol has 3 textboxes in it which I want to fill with data from a datasource.

```
 usercontrol uc = new usercontrol();
 flowlayoutpanel.Controls.Add(uc);
 uc.DataSource?
```

I know that in silverlight and ASP.NET you can add a datasource to a usercontrol. In the usercontrol you get the data into the textboxes by using `{Binding fieldname}` as their content. I can't find any information on this for Windows Forms.

Thanks for the help.
Thomas

Comment: Be aware that technologies such as Silverlight contain a more involved and advanced way of databinding, where databinding is still sort of an afterthought in WinForms. Stuart's answer is a great place to start, and specifically for your problem, you'll probably end up binding directly to your textboxes and not at all any of the container controls (act as if your usercontrol only contains three textboxes and nothing else).

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using getters and setters inside the user control. 
Seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this (thanks to the link of Stuart) by putting setters and getters in my usercontrol.

```
public partial class ucOpleiding : UserControl
{
   public string Datum
   {
        get { return txtDatum.Text; }
        set { txtDatum.Text = value; }
   }

   public string Plaats
   {
       get { return txtPlaats.Text; }
       set { txtPlaats.Text = value; }
   }

   public string Omschrijving
   {
       get { return txtOmschrijving.Text; }
       set { txtOmschrijving.Text = value; }
   }

    public ucOpleiding()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And in my main form I will then call those setters and getters.

```
foreach (opleiding opl in ChauffeurManagement.getOpleidingen(Int32.Parse(cbbID.SelectedValue.ToString())))
{
     ucOpleiding uc = new ucOpleiding();

     uc.Datum = opl.datum.ToString();
     uc.Plaats = opl.plaats_instantie;
     uc.Omschrijving = opl.omschrijving;

     flpOpleidingen.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's an article on MSDN which might help you implement this - [Walkthrough: Creating a User Control that Supports Simple Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171926%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (see also [Complex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms233813%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms233787%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Data binding walkthroughs).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but when they tell you to find `PhoneNumberBox` I cannot find it in the list of Associated Controls.